# How do I vectorize an image (bmp) of text to resemble actual text?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, font-identification, typography

I have .bmp of some text that needs to be vectorized, when I use image trace it comes out horrible and doesn't look like the text. If I knew what font they used I would just use the font and vector it. I'm working with just this low res image of text and they want it vector. Using the pen tool to draw each letter will take forever, I'm not sure what to do :([image]

above is the exact image of the text I need to vector (so the client can blow it up.

Comment: Figure out the font would be the easiest solution.

Comment: If you're stuck with a low-res image to begin with, there's no real benefit of turning that into a vector file (as you've found out). What they probably are asking is that you find the original font. If you can't then I'd just live with the lo-res bmp.

Answer (score 1):

Upload a portion of your .bmp to https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/ and hope that the font can be recognized.  Otherwise, find a similar font and go with that.

Comment: This works pretty well. That image is pretty low-red, but it should be able to get close.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a font is not an easy task, even if you only need to create a few letters. And it’s even worse if you have no experience with it.

You have to match several distances, angles and shapes to each other, you have to properly align the letters to each other, etc. Though this does not directly relate to your problem, it is quite illustrating that [rasterising text](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hint) is a science on its own.

Expert font creators may spend years on creating a font. Though they do not have a sample to start with and need to create more than just a few letters, this should give you an idea of the time required for this. And just to back this up somewhat: In the last three years, I spent large portions of my free time on digitalising an existing analogue font.

Therefore identifying the font will almost certainly be the best way to go. You can even ask font-identifying questions here (after you have tried the automated resources). For more details, take a look at [the tag wiki](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/tags/font-identification/info) for [font-identification](/questions/tagged/font-identification).